# Schedule task for a specific date & time in android

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I'm tying to make a app schedules task, for example 28th of april at 5am I need to check a file on my server, for example if there is a Update for the app. But if the user his phone is shutdown at that time the task needs to be executed at the best time possible, next bootup & when the phone is conencted to the internet?

I can't figure out how I can do this? I can't find a framework or Classes in the Android API that can do This task in android.

Anyone who knows a way to do this and what the best way is for performance, battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is the type that is better solved by a tutorial; I would suggest looking into the AlarmManager [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and even checking chapter 26: Background Services on The Big Nerd Ranch: Android Programming Guide; if not maybe a simple tutorial on how to create an alarm clock app might help.

Comment: Yes I have looked in to this, but the biggest question is what if at that moment there isn't network available or the phone isn't powered on

Comment: For connectivity, you'd have to check getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); for bootup you'd need a receiver that executes the action on bootup [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android). Again this doesn't cover all, you need tutorials to actually understand what's going on

Comment: Thanks I just finished my app with a complete working alarmsystem :D thanks!