# Android: Check whether the App is in background or Closed

Tags: android, session, authentication, background, logout

In my project I need to distinguish between the app being in the background or the app was closed.

Example:
I start up my app, and I log in, but I don't check the Stay logged in box. So If I close the App, It should log me out before it closes. (This is easily acquirable) BUT: The app can open google maps, and dial screen, which also puts the app in the background, so the Activity's onStop will be called too. And If I return from these screens to the App, I should remain logged in.

Comment: You are starting Google Maps with an Intent so you know exactly that you did not close the app. Store a flag to represent that and check it in your `onStop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overcame the problem by creating a boolean in MainActivity, and since it only has value when the Activity lives, it can be used when reopening the app or getting back to the app from background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it on the onDestroy, but if the user kills the app from the multitask menu, the onDestroy will not be called, so what I do. I scedule a task that needs to be executed in 10 minutes, if the user haven't come back to the app (I check this with a boolean in the sharedprefs, setting in onresume) I log the user out.

I figured it out with this -> [Schedule task for a specific date & time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505778/schedule-task-for-a-specific-date-time-in-android)

Comment: I'll have a look, Thank you.

Comment: if you get it working, or think it was usefull, please mark as solution & upvote ;)

Comment: Overcame the problem by creating a boolean in MainActivity, and since it only has value when the Activity lives, it can be used when reopening the app:

Comment: it is possible that the garbage collection closes your app when there is not enough memory left, at that point you wont be able to use your method

Comment: That's not a problem in our scenario. Otherwise it would really need an another coding.